# Get value from xml using xpath

Tags: php, xml

I have word document converted to xml file, this is a part of this file:

```
<w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2130" w:type="dxa"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00255D05" w:rsidRPr="00FF409F" w:rsidRDefault="00255D05" w:rsidP="00D041E7">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:hint="cs"/>
                <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
                <w:rtl/>
                <w:lang w:bidi="ar-JO"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00FF409F">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:hint="cs"/>
                <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
                <w:rtl/>
                <w:lang w:bidi="ar-JO"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>myWantedText</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:tc>
```

I am trying to get the value of 'myWantedText', so far i have tried:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($fileContents);
foreach($xml->xpath('//w:t') as $t) {
    var_dump($t);
}
```

but all i am getting is a punch of `object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lacking a [namespace in the input XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) and a declaration as Stuart Pointed out. Below is your XML, with the correct [Word XML Namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2005/07/05/intro-to-word-xml-part-1-simple-word-document.aspx).

```
<?php

$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<w:tc xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
    <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2130" w:type="dxa"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00255D05" w:rsidRPr="00FF409F" w:rsidRDefault="00255D05" w:rsidP="00D041E7">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:hint="cs"/>
                <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
                <w:rtl/>
                <w:lang w:bidi="ar-JO"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00FF409F">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:hint="cs"/>
                <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
                <w:rtl/>
                <w:lang w:bidi="ar-JO"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>myWantedText</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:tc>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('w', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml');
foreach($xml->xpath('//w:t') as $t) {
    var_dump($t);
}
?>
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "myWantedText"
}
```

You can see this working here: http://codepad.org/YRIO6uk3

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code entirely, but all i get is `object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]`

Comment: @alliawwad change `var_dump($t);` to `echo $t;` This is a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the character ":" messes up the call to xpath.

As a workaround you can do:

```
<?php

$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="2130" w:type="dxa"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00255D05" w:rsidRPr="00FF409F" w:rsidRDefault="00255D05" w:rsidP="00D041E7">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:hint="cs"/>
                <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
                <w:rtl/>
                <w:lang w:bidi="ar-JO"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="00FF409F">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:hint="cs"/>
                <w:sz w:val="36"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="36"/>
                <w:rtl/>
                <w:lang w:bidi="ar-JO"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>myWantedText</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:tc>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$result = $xml->xpath('/*');
echo $result[0]->p->r->t;
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
myWantedText
```

**UPDATE:**
[Lego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18952288/1057429) is better than this work around!

Comment: i get `Trying to get property of non-object` , and if i try `var_dump($result[0]->p->r);` i get `null`

Comment: Did you parse the xml using /* ?

Comment: @alliawwad I updated the answer to contain the full code (including output). Are you doing the exact same thing ?

Comment: `:` is perfectly valid in XML as the Namespace delimiter. Apart from the missing namespace declaration, there's nothing wrong with the XML